# Can you tell apart devices with media queries without using device width?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, mobile-devices

Is there a way to tell apart devices with media queries other than using the devices with? I find that this is not sufficient enough, as there are mobile devices that have higher resolutions than some desktops (such as the iPad Pro).

So what if I want to show tablet users a different view than desktop users? Is this possible with CSS?